# I want to access the each cell of the datatable. How?

Tags: c#, datatable

Using C#, I want to access each cell in every row in a datatable. What's the best practice to do it?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (myQuantity[i]!=null && myQuantity[i].Length>0)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = myName[i];
            row["Quantity"] = myQuantity[i];
            row["Price"] = myPrice[i];

            c = Convert.ToInt32(myQuantity[i]);

            int price = Convert.ToInt32(myPrice[i]) * c;


            row["Amount"] = price;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you are having?

Comment: can please explain in more detail ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could loop through the rows accessing each cell:

```
int numberOfColumns = dt.Columns.Count;

// go through each row
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    // go through each column in the row
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        // access cell as set or get
        // dr[i] = "something";
        // string something = Convert.ToString(dr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. I can access each cell of the each row. Thanku so much :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `foreach` loop for `DataRow` as well as `DataColumn`, Something on the following line...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr[dc]);
    }
```